# Return the furthermost outlier in kmeans clustering?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

Is there any easy way to return the furthermost outlier after sklearn kmeans clustering?

Essentially I want to make a list of the biggest outliers for a load of clusters. Unfortunately I **need** to use sklearn.cluster.KMeans due to the assignment.

Comment: Show some own attempt and ideas. There is not even a single line of code here! All you need is ```X```, ```kmeans.cluster_centers_```, ```kmeans.labels_``` (attributes in documentation) and a bit of numpy (like ```np.argsort``` and co.).

Comment: Yeah this is how I am doing it, I meant is there a function that can be used to return distances rather than them being calculated afterwards

Comment: The you should have mentioned and shown it! There is ```kmeans.inertia_``` (which is squared!). What's wrong with reading the docs?

Comment: `inertia_` gives the sum of squared distances, which does not seem so helpful here; `KMeans.transform()` gives the individual distances though.

Answer (score 3):

K-means is not well suited for "outlier" detection.

k-means has a tendency to make outliers a one-element cluster. Then the outliers have the *smallest* possible distance and will not be detected.

K-means is not robust enough when there are outliers in your data. You may actually want to **remove outliers prior to using k-means**.

Use rather something like kNN, LOF or LoOP instead.

Answer (score 2):

Sascha basically gives it away in the comments, but if `X` denotes your data, and `model` the instance of `KMeans`, you can sort the values of `X` by the distance to their centers through

```
X[np.argsort(np.linalg.norm(X - model.cluster_centers_[model.labels_], axis=1))]
```

Alternatively, since you know that each point is assigned to the cluster whose center minimizes Euclidean distance to the point, you can fit and sort in one step through

```
X[np.argsort(np.min(KMeans(n_clusters=2).fit_transform(X), axis=1))]
```