# Is there is a way to print outliers after finishing K-means in sklearn? let's say the top 5

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

preparing data

```
df= rn.read_sql(sql,conn)
Data = df.as_matrix(['TOT_CLM_GROSS_AMT','UNIT_PRICE','QUANTITY'])
```

applying K-means

```
kmeansFinal = KMeans(n_clusters = 47, init="k-means++",precompute_distances=True, copy_x=True,max_iter=500,n_init=20 ).fit(Data)
```

then computing the distance

```
distances= kmeansFinal.transform(Data)
```

I want to print the values of the first n outliers
let's say n is 5 for now

Comment: K-means hates outliers. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47489705/return-the-furthermost-outlier-in-kmeans-clustering).

Answer (score 0):

After you computed your `distance`, choose `n` and run:

```
n = 5
outliers = [x[0] for x in sorted(enumerate(distances), key=lambda x: sum(x[1]**2)**0.5, reverse=True)[:n]]
```

Now, `outliers` hold the index of the data points in `Data` which are furthest from their centroids.

```
for outlier in outliers:
    print(Data[outlier])
```